# TensorFlow's random_poisson only runs on CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to get TensorFlow's `random_poisson` function to run on my GPU; given that [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/random/random_poisson_test.py) TensorFlow source page has a function `testCPUGPUMatch` that compares the outputs of `random_poisson` when run on the CPU and on the GPU, it seems like it should be possible. However, when testing with the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        test = sess.run(tf.random_poisson(1.0, [], dtype=tf.float64))
print(test)
```

I get the error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation
>   'random_poisson/RandomPoissonV2': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU
>   devices is available. Registered kernels:   device='CPU'; R in
>   [DT_INT64]; dtype in [DT_INT64]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_INT64]; dtype
>   in [DT_INT32]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_INT64]; dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
>   device='CPU'; R in [DT_INT64]; dtype in [DT_FLOAT]   device='CPU'; R
>   in [DT_INT64]; dtype in [DT_HALF]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_INT32];
>   dtype in [DT_INT64]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_INT32]; dtype in
>   [DT_INT32]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_INT32]; dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
>   device='CPU'; R in [DT_INT32]; dtype in [DT_FLOAT]   device='CPU'; R
>   in [DT_INT32]; dtype in [DT_HALF]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_DOUBLE];
>   dtype in [DT_INT64]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_DOUBLE]; dtype in
>   [DT_INT32]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_DOUBLE]; dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
>   device='CPU'; R in [DT_DOUBLE]; dtype in [DT_FLOAT]   device='CPU'; R
>   in [DT_DOUBLE]; dtype in [DT_HALF]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_FLOAT];
>   dtype in [DT_INT64]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_FLOAT]; dtype in
>   [DT_INT32]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_FLOAT]; dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
>   device='CPU'; R in [DT_FLOAT]; dtype in [DT_FLOAT]   device='CPU'; R
>   in [DT_FLOAT]; dtype in [DT_HALF]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_HALF];
>   dtype in [DT_INT64]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_HALF]; dtype in
>   [DT_INT32]   device='CPU'; R in [DT_HALF]; dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
>   device='CPU'; R in [DT_HALF]; dtype in [DT_FLOAT]   device='CPU'; R in
>   [DT_HALF]; dtype in [DT_HALF]
>
> [[Node: random_poisson/RandomPoissonV2 =
>   RandomPoissonV2[R=DT_DOUBLE, S=DT_INT32, dtype=DT_DOUBLE, seed=0,
>   seed2=0, _device="/device:GPU:0"](random_poisson/shape,
>   random_poisson/RandomPoissonV2/rate)]]

which lists no registered GPU kernels. The code behaves as expected when run on my CPU, as does similar code with `uniform_random` when run on my GPU. Am I somehow missing the GPU kernel for `random_poisson`? Does one not exist, even though the linked source page implies that one does? And if one does not exist, is there an implementation that runs on the GPU? This is currently the bottleneck in a fairly complicated model I've implemented, so it'd be nice to get it fixed. I'm running version 1.8.0 of TensorFlow (installed from pip) on Python 3.6.4 on Arch Linux, with CUDA version 9.0 and cuDNN version 7.0 on a GeForce GTX 1050.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GPU kernel for random poisson. In [random_poisson_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/random_poisson_op.cc#L322), only the CPU kernel is registered.

If you look at the `testCPUGPUMatch` code that you linked, it invokes [`self.test_session(use_gpu=True, ...)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py#L915), which *tries* to run ops on GPU if possible. Under the hood, `test_session` uses [`allow_soft_placement`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L356) to do this, which falls back to CPU if it is not possible to run an op on GPU. So the test actually runs the op on CPU.

[Aside: Why do we have a test that doesn't really do anything? It appears that `testCPUGPUMatch` is a test for many different random ops (see [`test_random_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/random/random_ops_test.py)), and the implementer of RandomPoisson may have added it for that reason. It seems like it would be better named `testCPUGPUMatchIfGPUImplementationExists`...]

Feel free to submit a feature request for a GPU kernel via a github issue, or submit a PR with an implementation.

Comment: Ah, yeah the fact that that test exists and doesn't really do anything is a bit confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        test = sess.run(tf.random_poisson(1.0, [], dtype=tf.float64))
print(test)
```

Comment: Won't that just place the operation on the CPU?

Comment: try logging the placement. config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,log_device_placement=True)

Comment: In my actual code (not just this toy example) I've been logging the device placements. That's where I saw that this operation was being assigned to my CPU, and led to me trying this toy example.